# CFDictionary with unmanaged string?

Tags: swift, accessibility

I'm trying to make a prompt work for Accessibility in OS X, but the constant is a weird format and don't know how to make it work.

```
 var options: [String:String] = [:]
 options[kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt] = "YES"
 print(AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options))
```

The second line is obviously an error because of the conflicting type. How can I make the key work as that type or in what way should I cast it to work for the request method call?

Comment: What do I need to import to make this work in a playground?

Comment: `ApplicationServices.framework`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing the string "YES" when you mean to pass a boolean. You can't do that. Since this is the only value we're passing, we can let Swift do all the magical bridging for us from `[String: Bool]`.

```
import Foundation
import ApplicationServices

var options: [String: Bool] = [:]
options[kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String] = true
print(AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options))
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much. This is probably the most annoying and hardest-to-find-info on of all the prompts. Even in the docs it's a bit weird. I got the value being a String-type form an older Objective-C example, so I wasn't sure if it was actually correct at all. Thanks again!

Comment: I noticed that the app doesn't show in the System Preferences > Security > Accessibility pane tho. Do I have to use my payed developer account to test it signed to make that work or register it specifically to OS X to make it become visible there too?

Comment: No, it should register itself, but you're probably doing something like running it from within Xcode. In that case, Xcode is the process requesting control. In the "do you want to grant access to" dialog, check what process is mentioned.

Comment: Ah yes I see that it popped there. The boolean is true too I see. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the ObjC example probably had `@YES` in it. That's a boolean in ObjC, not a string. It's a shortcut for `[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]`. In ObjC, the traditional boolean values are `YES` and `NO`.